# DataGridView background color

Tags: c#, datagridview

I need to change back color of dtg view. I have done it before, but I am unable to do so now. I am filling dtg from data table from SQL, then I apply this function:

```
    private void HighlightExpired (DataGridView dtg)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtg.Rows) 
        {
            if (row.IsNewRow) continue;
            if (row.Cells["colStatus"].Value.ToString() == "Expired")
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
```

but it just does not change the background color. Does anyone have any ideas, please?

Comment: Hi, do use the debugger to see if you hit the line where the color is set. Step into the loop and see where it takes you; if it isn't hit have a look at the various values in the conditions..! Always try the debugger before coming here - we can't do that for you, usually.

Comment: Have you tried setting the row.CellStyle.BackColor? Also, have you confirmed your code is being hit by debugging? It may be something simple like: row.Cells["colStatus"].Value.ToString().ToUpper() == "EXPIRED"

Comment: That kind of code is almost never needed.  The DGV has a rich set of events which allow you to do that sort of thing incrementally, as needed and will adjust dynamically when the user edits data.

Comment: Hey guys. Yeah i debugged it and i got inside in the lop.